# OverflowError:python int too large to convert to C long on win8

Tags: python, cython, pyinstaller

I am using pyPDF2 to do pdf merging stuff using python, the python code is then deployed with pyinstaller, The resulting exe runs fine on win7 but it shows error overflow error on win8. The exception happens in getNumPages() which returns the number of pages a pdf includes, I am attaching screenshots of exception.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sreepyre9fx5au8/20150302_045446_resized.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmcbaksnh0n4n49/20150302_045456_resized.jpg?dl=0

Comment: This is coding support, not program support.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this is coding issue, I am using pyPDF2 module in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Overflow error occurs in generic.py, Some PDFs (rare) include values exceeding the size of long, therefore the Overflow error. My Fork on github addresses this issue here.

https://github.com/linuxexp/PyPDF2

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an internal stack error rather than something wrong with the program. You may want to try the Microsoft documentation on the issue, or maybe switch to Linux/Win7 if it seems like too much of a hassle.

support.microsoft.com/kb/145799